# Drupal Commerce "let me know when the price goes down"

Tags: commerce, rules, flags

I've been trying to create a price alert for products of which price dropped (let users flag that product and e-mail them when that product's price drops). For this purpose, I installed [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and have been trying to make such a thing with it and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). Am I on the right track? If not, what can I do?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In product content type add a new radio field "Would you like to receive an email if the product price change?" with options Yes and No.

Install [Token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) and [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

You can write a rule to send an email whenever the product node price field is updated to only users who has selected Yes option. you can do this by adding a standard available condition or you can execute a custom php code and use Token to access the radio button value.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), and creating a rule still working on it though. Can't add it here (too long) so I can send the export to whoever wishes.